# "Unhandled JS Exception: t is not a function. (In 't(c)', 't' is false)" on Production bundle React Native

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native, bundler

React Native version: 0.58.3

When building the release bundle, on both platforms, the app crashes on launch or gets stuck on the black screen on iOS.

But on the Dev Mode everything runs smoothly.

Log:

```
2019-09-18 14:43:52.964246+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491677]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2019-09-18 14:43:53.052680+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491677] 5.17.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50600000 started
2019-09-18 14:43:53.055493+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491677] 5.17.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2019-09-18 14:43:53.060321+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491697] 5.17.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2019-09-18 14:43:53.118524+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491639] [MediaRemote] [AVOutputContext] WARNING: AVF context unavailable for +[MRAVOutputContext sharedAudioPresentationContext]_block_invoke
2019-09-18 14:43:53.118777+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491639] [MediaRemote] [AVOutputContext] WARNING: AVF context unavailable for SYSTEM
2019-09-18 14:43:53.133669+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491639] NfcManager created
2019-09-18 14:43:53.255271+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491678] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fb876600d20] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-09-18 14:43:53.256357+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491678] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fb876600d20] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-09-18 14:43:53.256949+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491678] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-09-18 14:43:53.257744+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491678] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-09-18 14:43:53.270 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] t is not a function. (In 't(c)', 't' is false)
2019-09-18 14:43:53.271102+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491706] t is not a function. (In 't(c)', 't' is false)
2019-09-18 14:43:53.273 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: t is not a function. (In 't(c)', 't' is false)
2019-09-18 14:43:53.272959+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491679] Unhandled JS Exception: t is not a function. (In 't(c)', 't' is false)
2019-09-18 14:43:53.273 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2019-09-18 14:43:53.273202+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491706] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2019-09-18 14:43:53.285672+0200 APP_NAME[18561:1491679] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: t is not a function. (In 't(c)', 't' is false)', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: t is not a function. (In 't(c)', 't' is false), stack:
```

I think it has something to do with the `__DEV__` constant, as im using it through out the code to decided between environments and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out that was with redux and there a null value in the applyMiddleware function

https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger#log-only-in-development